# How can I make a jQuery UI slider detect mouseup after being clicked

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-events

I'm using the [jQuery slider](https://jqueryui.com/slider/) in my program and trying to make release of the slider trigger an event that updates the database. What I have is:

```
$('.ui-slider-handle').mouseup(function () {
    var $span = $(this).closest('#sliders').find('span.value'); // the span element that holds the value associated with the slider that was clicked
    $.ajax({
        method: 'POST',
        url: '/UpdateAnswer',
        data: {
            Answer: {
                QuestionId: $span.attr('data-qstnid'),
                AnswerId: $span.attr('data-answid'),
                AnswerVal: parseInt($span.text(), 10)
            },
            pid: $('input[name="pid"]').val()
        }
    });
});
```

and this works fine except in one type of unexpected situation: when the holds down the mouse button on the slider, moves the slider, then **moves their mouse off the slider before releasing the mouse**. In that situation the `$span` that is the slider is not defined.

What is the best way to solve this? Does JavaScript/jQuery have a natural way of doing this? Or am I going to have to create a `mousedown` handler that passes the element to some other function that then attaches a `mouseup` handler ... or  something like that?

Let me know if I need to go into more detail to describe my situation properly.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a `mouseup` event, you should probably be using the [change](http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/#event-change) or [stop](http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/#event-stop) events of the slider itself.

```
$( ".selector" ).on( "slidechange", function( event, ui ) {} );
```

or

```
$( ".selector" ).on( "slidestop", function( event, ui ) {} );
```

Comment: What is `.selector` supposed to be selecting?

Comment: The element you've created the UI Slider on.  You can also add the event handler as and option when creating the Slider.  Read the linked API documentation for examples.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the jQueryUI event `stop`, they have already figured this out for you. From the [documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/#event-stop):

```
$( ".selector" ).on( "slidestop", function( event, ui ) {} );
```